# Can anyone tell me what the "about 8 hours" means in sonar on the redundant modifier check?

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube

[image]

I have seen this on other checks as well, but there are many without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tells you when this violation was first discovered by Sonar.